# Docker Container VNC initial frame very slow

Tags: fedora, docker, vnc, tightvnc

I have a system running Fedora server 39 and docker. I am running docker containers that I want to VNC into.

While this does work the initial connection can take up to five minutes or so.

I am using TightVNC as the viewer.

I have observed this behavior on other versions (36, 37), different clients (Remmina, UltraVNC) and different hardware configurations. If I run this setup in Ubuntu it works just fine.

A better description of what happens:

- I open the client and put in the IP address:port of what I want to connect to
- Hit connect the window does not timeout or do anything it just sits for up to 5min.
- The window comes up with the container I want to vnc into it just fine
- Speed once the connection has been established is perfectly fine.

Does anyone have some suggestions of what I can do to make this connect to the containers quicker?

---

**UPDATE**: Should have put it in the original post, but this is using a MacVLAN.

Comment: It sounds like a reverse DNS lookup issue with the Docker container. Perhaps a reverse DNS setting needs to be set to be disabled?

Comment: I did not think it would use reverse DNS if I am typing the ip address directly? Should have put it in the original post, but this is using a MACVLAN

Comment: Reverse DNS resolves IP addresses on the server side. It does it for logging and possible filtering efforts. So access via hostname or IP doesn’t matter; reverse DNS happens to validate things hostname-wise.

Comment: as far as I am aware i have nothing DNS setup in the container. If i do it is just whatever is default

Comment: Did you find a solution, I am also facing a similar problem?

Comment: After reading about macvlan it's clear there is a number of virtual network (incuding VLAN config) emulation/settings that you gave no info about. Maybe a broadcast storm is happening because docker virtual network macvlan isn't setup correctly. https://developers.redhat.com/blog/2018/10/22/introduction-to-linux-interfaces-for-virtual-networking#macvlan

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems, getting access to docker containers from the host OS. I used portainer as a gui, to build understanding and awareness of docker features. Using portainer, I created a new network, and allocated fixed IPs, and connected to the services via the port mapping. Use eg. macvlan or ipvlan, from memory. If that functions, you can work backwards from there to make it less tedious or manual.

See https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-macvlan/
(using the Shell/Console & caveats)

See https://docs.portainer.io/user/docker/networks/add
(using the GUI)

See https://www.howtogeek.com/devops/how-to-assign-a-static-ip-to-a-docker-container/
(using shell or console to publish the port mapping to the VNC service after the container is remade connected to the new network)